# Trying to learn regex, to find files of a certain length?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file that has a list of countries of various lengths. This file is called `countries` and is in my working directory.

I want to run a the `grep` command that tells me which countries have nine or more letters.

I am struggling with getting the syntax correct at present.

Am I looking along the lines of:

```
grep '^.\{9\}' countries
```

Just tried the above and it seemed to do nothing at all?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Can you update your question posting a sample of the `countries` file content (use the [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/472926/edit) button)?

Comment: Please also clarify whether you are trying to match *files* of a certain length (as in your title) or *lines* of a certain length (as suggested by your grep expression)

Comment: I am just trying to return an answer that tells me how many countries are exactly nine characters

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me; will return all words with nine or more characters (including spaces).

```
grep -oh '.\{9,\}' countries
```

Update after reading your question again; matches on letters only this time.
So, if you need a country name that is nine or more contiguous letters, this is my suggestion.

```
grep -ioh '[a-z]\{9,\}' countries
```

This would not match something like "West Germany". Depends if you consider the country name in this example as 11 or 12. However, the 'length' is equal to or greater than nine (9).

Comment: Well, that will return **lines** with 9 or more characters. If we assume that there is one word per line, then yes, that is words with 9 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "," (comma) to tell 9 or more characters:

```
grep '^.\{9,\}' countries
```

Comment: A line containing more than 9 characters also contains exactly 9 characters; extending the range should only make a difference if the expression is anchored to the line end like `^.\{9\}$` (or for example when using the `-x` whole-line match flag, or the `-o` flag to output only matching portions instead of matching lines)

Comment: I am none too sure that I explained what I was after very well, I need to return a count of the number of countries in a file that contain exactly nine characters. I seem to be returning very high numbers that cannot be correct. I certainly don't know of 89 countries with nine letters that's for sure!